# @ in C header file

Tags: c, io, operators, registerstartupscript

Reading a header file, which implements the mapping of I/O devices for a microcontroller, I stumbled about the following code snippet:

```
typedef union{
    unsigned char Byte; 
    struct
    {
         unsigned char BIT0          :1;
         unsigned char BIT1          :1; 
         ...
         unsigned char BIT7          :1;
    }Bits; 
}COP;

extern volatile COP _COP @(0x0000 + 0x000000006FUL);
```

I cannot make any sense of the last line since I do not know the @ Operator.

Comment: Read The F(ine) Manual of the toolchain!

Comment: Is it a Microchip MCU?

Comment: "...ROM library addresses are followed by an @ sign..."